# React setState update is happening late ( n-1) , it seems i am lagging by one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const handlePageChange = (page, itemCount) => {
    

   setActivePage(page); // This is how am updating my state variable 
 
   setItemsPerPage(itemCount); // This is how am updating my state variable 
  

  }
```

handlePageChange  is called from onclick() , but it seems like activepage update is happening late ( it seems i am lagging by one) , if I go to 2nd page my state variable of active page  will show 1

Comment: how did you check activePage variable update?

Comment: @WilliamWang , by putting debugger ,  also  by console.log(activePage) , i could see variable is not getting updated

Comment: Inside the handlePageChange function, if the parameters `page` and `itemCount` contain the correct values that you need then use them. State change doesn't happen immediately but only when the component is called the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `setActivePage` is the asynchronous method, you can't get the updated value immediately after `setActivePage`. You should use another useEffect with dependency to see the updated `activePage`.

```
const handlePageChange = (page, itemCount) => {
   setActivePage(page);
   console.log(activePage); // Old `activePage` value will be printed.
   ...
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(activePage) // print state variable inside useEffect.
}, [activePage]);
```